# Trouble adding second menu to Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm trying to add an additional menu to a Wordpress theme.

I've found in theme-functions.pnp where the original menu is defined.

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Menu Navigator */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
if ( function_exists('register_nav_menus') ) {
    add_theme_support( 'nav-menus' );
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Main Menu','colabsthemes' )
    ));    
}

if (!function_exists('colabs_nav_fallback')) {
function colabs_nav_fallback($div_id){
    if (is_array($div_id)){ $div_id = $div_id['theme_location']; }
    if ( $div_id == 'primary' ){
        wp_page_menu('depth=0&title_li=');
    }
}}


function replace_menu_div( $newel ) {
    $html4nav = array();
    $html4nav[0] = '/<div class="menu">/';
    $html4nav[1] = '/<\/div>/';
    $html5nav = array();
    $html5nav[0] = '<nav class="top-nav">';
    $html5nav[1] = '</nav>';
    ksort($html4nav);
    ksort($html5nav);
    return preg_replace($html4nav, $html5nav, $newel, 1);
    }
add_filter('wp_page_menu','replace_menu_div');
```

So now I'm trying to plug in a second menu. Directly under where the first menu is named, I've added

```
‘wedding-menu’ => __( 'Wedding Menu' )
```

When I go to the menus page, "Wedding Menu" shows up as a menu location, and I have it selected as the menu I want it to be.

I call for the menu in the page template (which I based off of how the primary menu is called for in the header):

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => ‘wedding-menu’, 'container_class' => 'top-nav', 'container' => 'nav', 'menu_class' => '', 'fallback_cb'=>'colabs_nav_fallback') );?><!-- .topnav -->
```

When I then load the webpage, the menu is exactly where I want it and how I want it to look, however no matter what I've tried, it shows the default menu in this spot, and not the new menu I added.

I'm not sure if there's something I should add or change to the if statement that follows where I name the menu. I've tried duplicating it, replacing primary with wedding-menu, but that made no change.

Thanks!